# Uncheck all radio buttons in PDF before print in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, forms, pdf, radio-button, unchecked

In my PDF form I've got some radio buttons checked by default and I need to make them unchecked before printing the form.

I've tried this but it didn't seem working:

```
function deleteDefault()
{
    for (let x of this.getElementsByClassName("radio")){
        x.checked = False;}
}
```

```
function deleteDefault()
{
    var x = this.getElementsByClassName("radio");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
        x[i].checked = False;}
}
```

I even tried to uncheck one after another like so:

```
function deleteDefault()
{
    this.getField("FieldName").checked = False;
}
```

.. but that didn't work nether.

Can someone please tell me where I'm making a mistake?
Thank you all, I'm just getting started with JavaScript

Comment: Can you define "PDF form"? Also, try lowercasing your boolean from "False" to "false".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out this way:

```
this.getField("FieldName").value = "Disapproved";
```

That works for a radio button.

For list box or simple text box this works just fine:

```
this.getField("FieldName").value = "";
```